# Converting list of strings to list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I want to convert a list `[bird, cake, day]` to `[(bird, 4), (cake, 4), (day, 3)]` which is `[(element, len(element))]` format.

I did

```
for element in a_list:
    element = tuple(element, len(element))
```

but getting tuple() takes at most 1 argument (2 given) error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Replace `tuple(element, len(element))` -> `tuple([element, len(element)])` Tuple takes in a single element or an iterable.

Comment: ``[(x, len(x)) for x in a_list]`` ?

Comment: there is no need of writing tuple `(element, len(element))` is a tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your getting that error because your passing two args to tuple(), this should work:

```
[tuple((element, len(element))) for element in a_list]
```

or shorter:

```
[(element, len(element)) for element in a_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst1 = ['bird', 'cake', 'day']
lst2 = [(i, len(i)) for i in lst1]
print(lst2)
```

OUT:

```
[('bird', 4), ('cake', 4), ('day', 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assumed your `a_list` is string. This works.

```py
a_list = ["bird", "cake", "day"]
new_list = []

for element in a_list:
    new_list.append([element, len(element)])

print(new_list)
```

[['bird', 4], ['cake', 4], ['day', 3]]

The reason your code is not working is you updating the `element` reference in the for loop. Which is not an identical reference to the value in the `a_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using list comprehension:

```
element = ["bird", "cake", "day"]
new_list = [(i, len(i)) for i in element]
print(new_list)
```